# Mahout build errors in idea

Tags: mahout

I'm just starting out with Mahout, and got the latest from git, but it comes up with about a hundred or so errors when I build the project (exclusively in the 'math' section), such as:

```
import org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenIntHashSet;
```

"Cannot resolve symbol OpenIntHashSet"

Similar problems exist for DoubleArrayList, DoubleDoubleProcedure, and others.

Comment: Are you sure this is build error? Looks like runtime error. Can you post the entire error log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the project's Maven configuration.